# Error with using length function; output will not be anything other than one

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, dataset

I have multiple csv files I've uploaded into both google colab and jupyter notebook. I can successfully print certain lines of my file. The file contains rows of strings. When I open the file it opens the number application of my MacBook. Anyways, for some reason whenever I try to print the length of ANY line in my file, python ALWAYS tells me the length is 1. All of the strings have way more than a length of 1. I thought "maybe it's the file itself?" Nope. Ive used multiple csv files, still 1. Its not the ide, I've used jupyter and google colab. I can print the lengths of words like 'HELLO'. But, nothing correctly that's in my file. Im assuming I have something wrong with my code even though I've tried multiple versions. Please let me know what's going on. This is a simple command yet for some reason it is not working.

```
with open('/Users/xxx/Desktop/Silkscreen/fonts/ughuuh.csv' , newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)
    print((len(data[1]))
    >>output: 1
```

Comment: What is the result of `print(len(data))`?

Comment: It gives me 159. This is the total number of rows in my file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to this:

```py
print(len(data[1]))
```

I am making some assumptions about "data" but it looks like you are getting a list of lists.

so to use random:

```py
import random

data = [['(O)[C@@H](O)[C@H](O2)OC OC[C@@H](O)C(O)[C@H](O)C'],['(O)[C@@H](O)[C@H][C@H](O)C']]

rand = random.choice(data)
print(len(rand[0]))
```

Comment: I apologize, I accidentally put my code in incorrect. But the len still gives me the output of 1.

Comment: what is the result of ```print(data[1])``` might help you identify the length it's returning?

Comment: It prints this [‘(O)[C@@H](O)[C@H](O2)OC OC[C@@H](O)C(O)[C@H](O)C’] which is correct

Comment: ah.. try ```len(data[1][0])```

Comment: Do you know how to use this when I’m using random.choice(data)? When I use this the length comes out to zero.

Answer (score 0):

The len function takes an object as a function.

```
print(len(data[1]))
```

Comment: Still 1, unfortunately.